# ActiveRecord::Base Class Not Mutable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, immutability

I have a class I've extended from ActiveRecord::Base...

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and I collect the records from it like so...

```
records = @profile.all
```

which works fine, but it doesn't seem that I can successfully Update the attributes.  I don't want to save them back to the database, just modify them before I export them as JSON.  My question is, why can't I update these?  I'm doing the following (converting date formats before exporting):

```
        records.collect! { |record|
        unless record.term_start_date.nil?
            record.term_start_date = Date.parse(record.term_start_date.to_s).strftime('%Y,%m,%d')
        end

        unless record.term_end_date.nil? 
            record.term_end_date = Date.parse(record.term_end_date.to_s).strftime('%Y,%m,%d') 
        end

        record
    }
```

At first I had just been doing this in a do each loop, but tried collect! to see if it would fix things, but no difference.  What am I missing?

P.S. - I tried this in irb on one record and got the same results.

Comment: What's wrong?  Are you getting an error message?  How is the variable `@profile` defined?  What data type is the field `term_start_date`?

Comment: @bdares, no it's failing silently.  For instance, in irb...

>> r.term_start_date
=> Tue, 05 Sep 1995 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
>> r.term_start_date = Date.parse(r.term_start_date.to_s).strftime('%Y,%m,%d')
=> "1995,09,05"
>> r.term_start_date
=> Wed, 07 Nov 2012 00:19:59 UTC +00:00

#bigshrug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a different way to solve the problem, that keeps the logic encapsulated in the class itself.

Override the `as_json` instance method in your `Profile` class.

```
def as_json(options={})
  attrs = super(options)

  unless attrs['term_start_date'].nil?
    attrs['term_start_date'] = Date.parse(attrs['term_start_date'].to_s).strftime('%Y,%m,%d')
  end

  unless attrs['term_end_date'].nil? 
    attrs['term_end_date'] = Date.parse(attrs['term_end_date'].to_s).strftime('%Y,%m,%d') 
  end

  attrs
end
```

Now when you render the records to json, they'll automatically use this logic to generate the intermediate hash. You also don't run the risk of accidentally saving the formatted dates to the database.

You can also set up your own custom option name in the case that you don't want the formatting logic.

This [blog post](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/) explains in more detail.

Comment: Kelvin, this is perfect!  Code worked flawlessly copied/pasted in as is.  (Thanks for the effort of using my own code.)  

I can imagine a number of options and more general (non-fieldname-specific) implementation.  Spot on.  Thanks!

Comment: Still mystified about why simply using setters on the ActiveRecord::Base extended class doesn't work, but this gets me there.

Comment: @sands Nice! I didn't actually test the code - was hoping I didn't make a typo somewhere. As for why the setters didn't work, my guess is that AR prevented it because of a datatype mismatch (trying to store string into a timestamp column).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `record.save!` before `record`.

Actually, by using `collect!`, you just modifying records array, but to save modified record to database you should use `save` or `save!` (which raises exception if saving failed) on every record.

Comment: OP says "I don't want to save them"